# Should a semicolon be used with a conjunction and a dependent clause?

Tags: commas, conjunctions, semicolons, dependent-clause, independent-clauses

I've seen semicolons used to separate independent clauses, but is it correct to use them with an independent clause, a conjunction, and a dependent clause?

`<independent clause 1>`; but `<dependent clause 2>`

For example, consider this sentence:

> The product permits a dual use that provides all of the standard benefits of a typical standing **mat;** but also provides a more sports oriented mat in the same product.

Or since it is dependent, must it be a comma?

> The product permits a dual use that provides all of the standard benefits of a typical standing **mat,** but also provides a more sports oriented mat in the same product.

Comment: I can't understand either sentences.  I don't understand how you are using "but."  It's like you're saying but also provides something, as if it were a subject.

Comment: The product permits a dual use: it provides all of the standard benefits of a typical standing mat; it also doubles as a more sports oriented mat.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth is that what he means?

Comment: "Not only does the product provide all of the standard benefits, but it also doubles as a sports-oriented mat."

Comment: "The product provides the benefits of both a typical standing mat and a sports-oriented mat."  (whatever the hell we're talking about)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A semicolon is incorrect in this sentence, and it should in fact be a comma.

However, strictly speaking this sentence does not include a dependent clause, because there is no subject in the phrase after the word *but*. To illustrate this, let's remove some of the excess verbiage:

> The product permits a use, but also provides a mat.

(Eliminating the modifiers and streamlining it in this way also helps to illustrate why the comments on the original question pointed out that it's hard to interpret. The *product* "provides" a *mat*, which doesn't make much sense. But that doesn't change the discussion as to what is grammatically correct.)

So as you can see, there is one subject (product), and two verb phrases (permits a use / also provides a mat), and the two VPs are joined by the coordinating conjunction *but*.

Now, since you asked about dependent clauses: in general you would not expect to join dependent clauses to independent clauses with semicolons, either. For example (dependent clauses italicized):

> *Although I play soccer*, I prefer watching football.
>
> I enjoy watching TV *while I eat*.

Finally, it's worth noting that the construction *[clause], (coordinating conjunction) [clause]* is used to join two *independent* clauses, since each one (minus the coordinating conjunction) can stand on its own. For example (clauses separated in brackets):

> [I like chocolate], and [I love candy].
>
> [You read a book], but [you didn't enjoy it].

Note the use of a comma in each situation. You could alternatively use a semicolon, but *without* the conjunction:

> [I like chocolate]; [I love candy].
>
> [You read a book]; [you didn't enjoy it].